# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am working on android project and getting null object refrence

**DatabaseHelper class**

```
package com.example.smartpmr;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // DATABASE NAME
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PMR";

    // DATABASE VERSION
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // PATIENT TABLE
    private static final String TABLE_PATIENT = "tblPatient";

    // DOCTOR TABLE
    private static final String TABLE_DOCTOR = "tblDoctor";

    // PRESCRIPTION TABLE
    private static final String TABLE_PRESCRIPTION = "tblPrescription";

    // MEDICINE TABLE
    private static final String TABLE_MEDICINES = "tblMedicines";

    // PATIENT TABLE COLUMNS
    public static final String PATIENT_ID = "PATIENT_ID";
    public static final String PATIENT_NAME = "PATIENT_NAME";
    public static final String PATIENT_EMAIL = "PATIENT_EMAIL";
    public static final String PATIENT_PASSWORD = "PATIENT_PASSWORD";
    public static final String PATIENT_AGE = "PATIENT_AGE";
    public static final String PATIENT_CONTACT = "PATIENT_CONTACT";
    public static final String PATIENT_ADDRESS = "PATIENT_ADDRESS";

    // DOCTOR TABLE COLUMS
    public static final String DOCTOR_ID = "DOCTOR_ID";
    public static final String DOCTOR_NAME = "DOCTOR_NAME";
    public static final String DOCTOR_EMAIL = "DOCTOR_EMAIL";
    public static final String DOCTOR_PASSWORD = "DOCTOR_PASSWORD";
    public static final String DOCTOR_CONTACT = "DOCTOR_CONTACT";
    public static final String DOCTOR_SPECIALIZATION = "DOCTOR_SPECIALIZATION";

    // PRESCRIPTION TABLE COLUMS
    public static final String PRESCRIPTION_ID = "PRESCRIPTION_ID";
    public static final String FK_PATIENT_ID = "PATIENT_ID";
    public static final String PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_ID = "DOCTOR_ID";
    public static final String PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_NAME = "DOCTOR_NAME";
    public static final String DIAGNOSIS = "DIAGNOSIS";
    public static final String PRECAUTION = "PRECAUTION";
    public static final String ISSUE_DATE = "ISSUE_DATE";

    // MEDICINE TABLE COLUMS
    public static final String MEDICINE_ID = "MEDICINE_ID";
    public static final String FK_PRESCRIPTION_ID = "FK_PRESCRIPTION_ID";
    public static final String MEDICINE_NAME = "MEDICINE_NAME";
    public static final String MEDICINE_TYPE = "MEDICINE_TYPE";
    public static final String MEDICINE_DOSE = "MEDICINE_DOSE";
    public static final String START_DATE = "START_DATE";
    public static final String END_DATE = "END_DATE";


    // CREATING PATIENT TABLE IN DATABASE
    String CreatePatientTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATIENT + " ( " + PATIENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            + PATIENT_NAME + " TEXT , " + PATIENT_EMAIL + " TEXT , " + PATIENT_PASSWORD + " TEXT , " + PATIENT_AGE + " TEXT , "
            + PATIENT_CONTACT + " TEXT , " + PATIENT_ADDRESS + " TEXT ); ";


    // CREATING DOCTOR TABLE IN DATABASE
    String CreateDoctorTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DOCTOR + " ( " + DOCTOR_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
            + DOCTOR_NAME + " TEXT , " + DOCTOR_EMAIL + " TEXT , " + DOCTOR_PASSWORD + " TEXT , " + DOCTOR_CONTACT + " TEXT ,"
            + DOCTOR_SPECIALIZATION + " TEXT ); ";

    // CREATING PRESCRIPTION TABLES IN DATABASE

    String CreatePrescriptionTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + " ( " + PRESCRIPTION_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
            FK_PATIENT_ID + " TEXT , " + " FOREIGN KEY ( " + FK_PATIENT_ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_PATIENT + " ( " + PATIENT_ID + ")"
            + PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_ID + " TEXT , " + PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_NAME + " TEXT , " + DIAGNOSIS + " TEXT , " +
            PRECAUTION + " TEXT , " + ISSUE_DATE + " TEXT );";

    // CREATING MEDICINE TABLE IN DATABASE
    String CreateMedicineTabel = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDICINES + " ( " + MEDICINE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
            MEDICINE_NAME + " TEXT , " + MEDICINE_TYPE + " TEXT , " + MEDICINE_DOSE + " TEXT , " +
            START_DATE + " TEXT , " + END_DATE + " TEXT , " + FK_PRESCRIPTION_ID + " INTEGER , " +
            " FOREIGN KEY ( " + FK_PRESCRIPTION_ID + " ) REFERENCES " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + " ( " + PRESCRIPTION_ID + "));";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       db.execSQL(CreatePatientTable);
       db.execSQL(CreateDoctorTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

          db.execSQL(CreatePrescriptionTable);
          db.execSQL(CreateMedicineTabel);
    }

    // METHOD FOR CHECKING IF EMAIL EXISTS OR NOT
    public boolean CheckPatientMail(String patientEmail) {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PATIENT + " WHERE " + PATIENT_EMAIL + " = ? ", new String[] {patientEmail});
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }


       // METHOD FOR REGISTER PATIENT
    public boolean RegisterPatient(String patientName, String patientEmail, String patientPassword, String patientAge, String patientContact, String patientAddress) {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_NAME,patientName);
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_EMAIL,patientEmail);
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_PASSWORD,patientPassword);
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_AGE,patientAge);
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_CONTACT,patientContact);
        contentValues.put(PATIENT_ADDRESS,patientAddress);

        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_PATIENT,null,contentValues);

        if(insert == -1 ) return false;
        else return true;
    }
        // This getdata() method will be deleted later #reminder
    public String getdata() {
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] Columns = {PATIENT_ID,PATIENT_NAME,PATIENT_EMAIL,PATIENT_PASSWORD,PATIENT_AGE,PATIENT_CONTACT,PATIENT_ADDRESS};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PATIENT,Columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_ID);
        int ifname = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_NAME);
        int imail = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_EMAIL);
        int ipass = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_PASSWORD);
        int iage = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_AGE);
        int icontact = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_CONTACT);
        int iaddress = cursor.getColumnIndex(PATIENT_ADDRESS);

        for(cursor.moveToFirst();!cursor.isAfterLast();cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            result =  result + cursor.getString(iRow) + " \n " + cursor.getString(ifname) +
                    " \n " + cursor.getString(imail) + " \n " + cursor.getString(ipass) + " \n "
                    + cursor.getString(iage) + " \n " + cursor.getString(icontact) +
                     " \n " + cursor.getString(iaddress) + "\n";
        }
        return  result;
    }

      // METHOD FOR PATIENT LOGIN
    public boolean CheckPatientLogin(String patientMail, String patientPass) {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PATIENT + " WHERE " + PATIENT_EMAIL + " = ? AND " +
                                          PATIENT_PASSWORD + " = ? ", new String[] {patientMail,patientPass} );
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
            else return false;
    }

    // METHOD FOR CHECK EXISTING DOCTOR EMAIL

    public boolean CheckDoctorEmail(String doctorEmail) {

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DOCTOR + " WHERE " + DOCTOR_EMAIL + " = ? ", new String[]{doctorEmail});
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) return  false;
        else return true;
    }

    // METHOD FOR DOCTOR REGISTRATION

    public boolean RegisterDoctor(String doctorName, String doctorEmail, String doctorPassword, String doctorContact, String doctorSpecialization) {

       db = this.getWritableDatabase();

       ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
       contentValues.put(DOCTOR_NAME,doctorName);
       contentValues.put(DOCTOR_EMAIL,doctorEmail);
       contentValues.put(DOCTOR_PASSWORD,doctorPassword);
       contentValues.put(DOCTOR_CONTACT,doctorContact);
       contentValues.put(DOCTOR_SPECIALIZATION,doctorSpecialization);

       long insert = db.insert(TABLE_DOCTOR,null,contentValues);
       if(insert == -1 ) return false;
       else return true;

    }

    // METHOD FOR DOCTOR LOGIN
    public boolean CheckDoctorLogin(String doctorEmail, String doctorPassword) {

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DOCTOR + " WHERE " + DOCTOR_EMAIL + " = ? AND " +
                        DOCTOR_PASSWORD + " = ? ", new String[]{doctorEmail,doctorPassword});

        if(cursor.getCount()>0) return true;
        else return false;

    }

    // METHOD FOR GETTING PATIENT NAME AND ID  IN PATIENT PORTAL
    public Cursor getPatientNameAndId(String mail,String pass) {

        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + PATIENT_ID + " , " + PATIENT_NAME + " FROM " + TABLE_PATIENT + " WHERE "  + PATIENT_EMAIL + " = ? AND "
                + PATIENT_PASSWORD + "= ?", new String[] {mail,pass} );

        return cursor;
    }

    public boolean insertPrescription(String patientID, String docId, String docName, String diagnosis, String precaution, String issueDate) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(FK_PATIENT_ID,patientID);
        cv.put(PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_ID,docId);
        cv.put(PRESCRIPTION_DOCTOR_NAME,docName);
        cv.put(DIAGNOSIS,diagnosis);
        cv.put(PRECAUTION,precaution);
        cv.put(ISSUE_DATE,issueDate);
        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_PRESCRIPTION,null,cv);
        if(insert == -1)return false;
        else return true;

    }

    public int getPrescriptionId(String issueDate) {

        int id = 0;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + PRESCRIPTION_ID + " FROM " + TABLE_PRESCRIPTION + " WHERE " + ISSUE_DATE + " = ?" , new String[]{issueDate});

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(PRESCRIPTION_ID));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return id;
    }

    public boolean saveMedicine(String medName, String type, String dose, String startDate, String endDate, int prescriptionid) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MEDICINE_NAME,medName);
        cv.put(MEDICINE_TYPE,type);
        cv.put(MEDICINE_DOSE,dose);
        cv.put(START_DATE,startDate);
        cv.put(END_DATE,endDate);
        cv.put(FK_PRESCRIPTION_ID,prescriptionid);

        long insert = db.insert(TABLE_MEDICINES,null,cv);
        if(insert == -1) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

**add_medicine class**

```
package com.example.smartpmr;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class add_medicine extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    // widgets for popup medicine dialog
    Button saveMedicine,newMedicine;
    EditText medname,edtdose;
    EditText enddate,startdate;
    Spinner med_type_spinner;

    // widgets for prescription
    Button btnaddMedicine;
    EditText edtdoctorId,edtdoctorName,edtdiagnosis,edtprecaution;
    TextView tvselectDate,tvpatientId;

    String PatientID,medType;
    String[] medTypes = {"Select","Syrup","Injection","Tablet","Capsule"};

    int prescriptionId = -1;

    boolean insertMedicine;

    String medName;
    String type;
    String dose;
    String startDate;
    String endDate;


    DataBaseHelper db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_medicine);
        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        findViewsOfPrescriptionWidgets();

        Intent it = getIntent();
        PatientID = it.getStringExtra("id");
        tvpatientId.setText(PatientID);

        tvselectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog();
            }
        });

        // Button for save prescription data and popout medicine dialog
        btnaddMedicine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String docId = edtdoctorId.getText().toString();
                String docName = edtdoctorName.getText().toString();
                String diagnosis = edtdiagnosis.getText().toString();
                String precaution = edtdiagnosis.getText().toString();
                String issueDate = tvselectDate.getText().toString();

                boolean addPrescription = false;
                if(addPrescription == false){
                    addPrescription = db.insertPrescription(PatientID,docId,docName,diagnosis,precaution,issueDate);
                    if(addPrescription = true){
                        Toast.makeText(add_medicine.this, "Prescription Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          if(prescriptionId == -1 ){
                              prescriptionId = db.getPrescriptionId(issueDate);
                              Toast.makeText(add_medicine.this, "prescription id " + prescriptionId , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if(prescriptionId != -1){
                                popout_addmed();
                            }
                          }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog() {

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                this,
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
                Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

    private void findViewsOfPrescriptionWidgets() {
       tvpatientId = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pid);
       edtdoctorId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.docid);
       edtdoctorName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.docname);
       edtdiagnosis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.diagnosis);
       edtprecaution = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.precaution);
       btnaddMedicine=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddmed);
       tvselectDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prescriptiondate);


    }

    // Method for show popout for medicies
    public  void popout_addmed()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View mview=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.diaglog_layout,null);
        medname=(EditText) mview.findViewById(R.id.edtmedicine);
        med_type_spinner=(Spinner)mview.findViewById(R.id.spinermedtype);
        edtdose = (EditText)mview.findViewById(R.id.edtdosage);
        startdate=(EditText) mview.findViewById(R.id.edtSTARTDATE);
        enddate=(EditText) mview.findViewById(R.id.edtENDDATE);
        saveMedicine = (Button)mview.findViewById(R.id.btnsavemed);
        newMedicine = (Button)mview.findViewById(R.id.btnnewMedicine);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,medTypes);
        med_type_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        med_type_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int index = med_type_spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
                medType = medTypes[index];
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        builder.setView(mview);
        builder.show();

        newMedicine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 medName = medname.getText().toString();
                 type = medType;
                 dose = edtdose.getText().toString();
                 startDate = startdate.getText().toString();
                 endDate = enddate.getText().toString();

                insertMedicine = db.saveMedicine(medName,type,dose,startDate,endDate,prescriptionId);
                if(insertMedicine == true){
                    Toast.makeText(add_medicine.this, "medicine added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    clearMedicineField();
                }

            }
        });


        saveMedicine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                medName = medname.getText().toString();
                type = medType;
                dose = edtdose.getText().toString();
                startDate = startdate.getText().toString();
                endDate = enddate.getText().toString();
                insertMedicine = db.saveMedicine(medName,type,dose,startDate,endDate,prescriptionId);
                if(insertMedicine == true){
                    Toast.makeText(add_medicine.this, "medicine added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    clearMedicineField();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void clearMedicineField() {

        medname.getText().toString();
        edtdose.getText().toString();
        startdate.getText().toString();
        enddate.getText().toString();
        med_type_spinner.setSelection(0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
           month = month+1;
           String date = dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year;
           tvselectDate.setText(date);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-07-10 18:10:44.548 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2019-07-10 18:10:44.549 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2019-07-10 18:10:44.550 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.smartpmr-PSqLLORH7vlTbHptFqzWmQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2019-07-10 18:10:49.431 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2460 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
2019-07-10 18:10:54.149 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
2019-07-10 18:10:54.150 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=28KB
2019-07-10 18:10:58.221 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=61KB, data=57KB
2019-07-10 18:10:58.229 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=61KB, data=57KB
2019-07-10 18:11:03.936 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=123KB, data=99KB
2019-07-10 18:11:03.938 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=117KB, data=69KB
2019-07-10 18:11:08.364 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=90KB
2019-07-10 18:11:08.365 9933-9938/com.example.smartpmr I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=90KB
2019-07-10 18:11:10.528 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3092 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2019-07-10 18:11:12.289 9933-9933/com.example.smartpmr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.smartpmr, PID: 9933
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.smartpmr.DataBaseHelper.insertPrescription(DataBaseHelper.java:229)
        at com.example.smartpmr.add_medicine$2.onClick(add_medicine.java:78)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not initialize `db` in the methods `insertPrescription()` and `saveMedicine()` (like you did correctly in the other methods):

```
db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

so `db` is null when you use it.